# Login using external API in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

Currently I tried to login using username and password from external API https://fakestoreapi.com/auth/login with HTTP client that if login success will receive a token.

Now I have to make an error message and return to login form if username and password wrong. But what I get still an error from laravel like **Attempt to read property "token" on null**. Please help me, I'm a beginner.

This is my controller code.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class MasukController extends Controller
{
    public function masuk()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function cek(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        // Send a POST request to the API
        $response = Http::post('https://fakestoreapi.com/auth/login', [
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
        ]);

        // Decode the response
        $data = json_decode($response);

        // Get the token from the response
        $token = $data->token;

        // Redirect to the dashboard page
        if (is_null($token)) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Error: Token is null');

            // Redirect the user back to the previous page
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            session(['token' => $token]);
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show error message if username and password not match in login form.

Comment: please check if the `$response` return something.you can use `dd($response)`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use `GuzzleHttp\Client` when you execute post method.

for example using guzzlehttp below :

```html
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    public function PostData(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $username = $request->username;
        $password = $request->password;
            $url = 'https://yoururl.example'

        $params = [
            "username" => $username,
            "password" => $password
        ];

        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'json' => $params
        ]);

        return json_decode($response->getBody());
    }
```

Then you can dump & die / dd the response->getBody() for get output

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to json_decode the entire $response object which will fail. There is easier way get this done:

Gets an array of all response data:

```
$data = $response->json();
```

To get just the token:

```
$token = $response->json('token')
```